# Python edit distance

Tags: python, sequence, edit, distance, biopython

I am a molecular biologist using Biopython to analyze mutations in genes and my problem is this:

I have a file containing many different sequences (millions), most of which are duplicates. I need to find the duplicates and discard them, keeping one copy of each unique sequence. I was planning on using the module editdist to calculate the edit distance between them all to determine which ones the duplicates are, but editdist can only work with 2 strings, not files.

Anyone know how I can use that module with files instead of strings?

Comment: read in the file and split it into words then just compare the words?

Comment: Can you post some more information about what the file contains? Is each line a sequence? are there markers such as 'BEGIN SEQUENCE' or 'END SEQUENCE?' ?

Comment: Are you actually interested in near-duplicates (for which editdist could be useful), or actual duplicates?

Comment: I don't know a lot about molecular biology, but basically, what you have is a list of strings (sequences?), and you want them to be unique (no two strings are the same), right? If so, perhaps the `set` (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) type in Python can help you! As Russel said before me, that only works if you're looking for exact duplicates.

Comment: the file contains the sequence and sequence id. There are no markers, just line breaks between different sequences

Comment: basically what i want to do is read through all the sequences, discard all duplicates, and write the unique ones to a new file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file consists solely of sequences arranged one sequence per line, I would suggest the following:

```
seq_file = open(#your file)

sequences = [seq for seq in seq_file]

uniques = list(set(sequences))
```

Assuming you have the memory for it. How many millions?

ETA:

Was reading the comments above (but don't have comment privs) - assuming the sequence IDs are the same for any duplicates, this will work. If duplicate sequences can different sequence IDs, then would to know which comes first and what is between them in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out exact duplicates, you can use the `set` Python built-in type. As an example :

```
a = ["tccggatcc", "actcctgct", "tccggatcc"] # You have a list of sequences
s = set(a) # Put that into a set
```

`s` is then equal to `['tccggatcc', 'actcctgct']`, without duplicates.

Comment: Probably, yes. This is the simple, no-brainer solution, but it would work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: If "most of them" are duplicates, perhaps using them as dict keys as you parse the file like `for sequence in lot_of_sequences: dict.setdefault(sequence)` will consume much less memory.

Comment: If you can stream your values (as opposed to reading them all at once in a big list), you can use iterators and the used memory will only grow as large as the number of unique items. This should work even with a really, really large item count.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be Python?

If the sequences are simply text strings one per line then a shell script will be very efficient:

```
sort input-file-name | uniq > output-file-name
```

This will do the job on files up to 2GB on 32 bit Linux.

If you are on Windows then install the GNU utils http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/summary.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of files! ;-)

I'm posting an example by assuming the following:

1. its a text-file
2. one sequence per line

-

```
filename = 'sequence.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as sqfile:
   sequences = sqfile.readlines() # now we have a list of strings

#discarding the duplicates:
uniques = list(set(sequences))
```

That's it - by using pythons set-type we eliminate all duplicates automagically.

if you have the id and the sequence in the same line like:

```
423401 ttacguactg
```

you may want to eliminate the ids like:

```
sequences = [s.strip().split()[-1] for s in sequences]
```

with strip we strip the string from leading and trailing whitespaces and with split we split the line/string into 2 components: the id, and the sequence.
with the [-1] we select the last component (= the sequence-string) and repack it into our sequence-list.

Answer (score 0):

Four things come to mind:

1. You can use a set(), as described by F.X. - assuming the unique
   strings will all fit in memory
2. You can use one file per sequence, and feed the files to a program
   like equivs3e:
   http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/equivalence-classes.html#python-3e
3. You could perhaps use a gdbm as a set, instead of its usual
   key-value store use.  This is good if you need something that's 100%
   accurate, but you have too much data to fit all the uniques in
   Virtual Memory.
4. You could perhaps use a bloom filter to cut down the data to more
   manageable sizes, if you have a truly huge number of strings to
   check and lots of duplicates.  Basically a bloom filter can say
   "This is definitely not in the set" or "This is almost definitely in
   the set".  In this way, you can eliminate most of the obvious
   duplicates before using a more common means to operate on the
   remaining elements.
   http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/drs-bloom-filter/